# AEM6.2: com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error

Tags: aem, sling

We have AEM6.2 node environment and we are trying to access login.html but getting error as below.

After searching I came to know that java version could be one of the possible reason but I am already using Java 8 for this application. I am out of ideas. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
14.09.2018 14:08:40.299 *ERROR* [192.156.110.11 [1536948520114] GET /content/en/account/login.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script defaulttopnav
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:416)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491)
        at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.includeScript(IncludeTag.java:178)
        at com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:95)
        at org.apache.jsp.apps.components.navigation.topnavigation_jsp._jspService(navigation_jsp.java:329)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException:
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspExceptionInternal(JspServletWrapper.java:691)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:608)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:533)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
        ... 201 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.jsp.apps.components.topnavigation.defaulttopnav_jsp._jspService(defaulttopnav_jsp.java:347)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
        ... 206 common frames omitted
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Goto system/console and check if all bundles in active
2) Goto sling-->jsp and Recompile all jsp.
Might help.

Comment: @SaravanaPrakash, Apologies for responding late. I have recompiled all my jsp's and it has resolved the issue. I would be glad to accept this point as answer, if you can add it.

Comment: Thanks @rɑːdʒɑ, I added as answer :). glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution for errors are thrown by servlets compiled from jsp files, is to recompile the jsp again.

1. Goto system/console and verify if all bundles are in active state
2. Goto sling --> jsp and recompile all jsps.

This works if errors are thrown from otb jsp. However when custom application jsps throw error, you ll need to fix the custom jsp code by handling the error.

Another [foolproof](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ5JSPsNotRecompilingOnPackageInstallation.html) way to clear cached jsp class files is to delete /var/classes

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace indicates the NPE is stemming from `defaulttopnav_jsp.java`, line 347. Analysing the generated java file is the way to go.

Since AEM 6.1, the default ClassLoader was replaced by `FSClassLoader` and the generated `.java` files are no longer stored under `/var/classes`.

To locate the `.java` file you will need to locate the bundle ID for the `FSClassLoader` bundle, then the java files will be located at:

`[AEM_INSTALL_DIR]/crx-quickstart/launchpad/felix/bundle[BUNDLE_ID]/data/classes`

There is also a `sling` plugin which will help you view the generated java file from `OSGi` console. Check out [these](http://www.6dglobal.com/blog/new-apache-sling-fs-classloader-console-2015-06-23) [posts](https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2015/10/28/fsclassloader-now-in-aem6-0-sp3/) for that.